# pkexec asking for password multiple times

Tags: debian, security, password, pkexec

I have an application `foo` that starts other applications
(`bar` and `baz`) under the hood. 
I start `foo` using `pkexec`
and I have written a policy file for `foo` with:

```
<allow_any>yes</allow_any>
<allow_inactive>yes</allow_inactive>
<allow_active>yes</allow_active>
```

This way, it doesn't ask me for a password
when I run `pkexec --user <user> foo`. 
So far, so good. 
However, I recently made a change that first sets an environment var:
`pkexec --user <user> env BLA=$BLA && foo`. 
Now I get asked for passwords for all the other applications! 
I have to type the password for `bar`, `baz` and `env`. 
I can understand why it asks it for `env`, but why also for the others where in the first situation (without the `env`) it did not prompt?

I use Debian 9.4.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the syntax that works for debian 9:

pkexec --user  env BLA=$BLA foo

Answer (score -1):

Do

```
env BLA=$BLA pkexec --user <user> foo
```

or just

```
BLA=$BLA pkexec --user <user> foo
```

Comment: That does not seem to work. I need the env variables in the context of the pkexec.